# Image attachments throwing error in new WP migration

Tags: php, wordpress, image, attachment

I have a WP site that works fine in my testing environment. I migrated to a sub-directory on the clients server and now I'm having an issue with image attachments.

Fist of all, when I go to the media library, the images are all there, but the thumbnails are not showing, instead, they're replaced with a file icon. See screenshot-1 below.

Secondly, when I try to view the attachment page I'm getting the following errors:

Warning: Illegal string offset 'width' in /xxx/image.php on line 28

Warning: Illegal string offset 'height' in /xxx/image.php on line 29

Here's the code in the image.php file that is creating the issue:

```
$metadata = wp_get_attachment_metadata();
printf( __( 'Published <span class="entry-date"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%1$s" pubdate>%2$s</time></span> at <a href="%3$s" title="Link to full-size image">%4$s &times; %5$s</a> in <a href="%6$s" title="Return to %7$s" rel="gallery">%7$s</a>', 'detund' ),
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    wp_get_attachment_url(),
    $metadata['width'],
    $metadata['height'],
    get_permalink( $post->post_parent ),
    get_the_title( $post->post_parent )
);
```

Specifically, the `$metadata['width']` and  `$metadata['height']` sections.

Because of this, functions like WP's featured image, are not working.

Has anyone come across this before, or can anyone offer a solution for this issue?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: screenshot-1]

Comment: The first thing I would do is use my favorite browser's dev tools to inspect the img elements in the Media Library to see where it thinks the images are stored. It might be pointing to directories in your local environment still.

Comment: Thanks mark, if I inspect the element, it won't give me the thumbnail path. Instead it gives me the default thumb path that's currently being called to the interface; ei. xxx/wp-includes/images/media/default.png If however I one of the images, it does stated the path, which is correct, and yes the images are on the server with the same path.

Comment: **If however I open one of the images...

Comment: Are you able to get to the correct image by clicking on one of the media library files?

Comment: Well the correct path is listed in the URL field, but the image does not show up as it usually does. - It doesn't show up on the screen at all.

Comment: How strange. The next thing I would try is to add a new media file image, then go into the wp-posts and find your new file and compare it with one that is not working. post-type = attachment

Comment: Thanks mark, great idea. It does work, as should, when I re-upload the image using the WP media uploader. Unfortunately, this site has over 100 posts with several images in each post. I'd like to try to fix the error and avoid manually uploading each image again.

Comment: That's good. I feel that, I was suggesting seeing if you could find anything different between the way one freshly uploaded is stored in the db and one that isn't working. If you did find a difference, you could programmically change the ones not working to fit the working one's model

Comment: Yeah, I tried, no difference at all in SQL strings.

Comment: Guess at this point I'm just going reload every image by manually, annoying, but I can't make any sense out of the issue and it needs to get done. Thanks for your suggestions troubleshooting!

Answer (score 0):

Once I had this issue with one of my client. Jetpack plugin caused the problem. Try disabling it or even disable all active plugins and check whether you still have the problem. And even check your file permissions.

Also check your image url on whether it is pointing to your new url.

Comment: Thanks Vijayabalaji, I did try disabling all plugins, to no avail. image URLs are correct. File permissions are set to 644 which is how I always have them configured - without issue.